# Does syntaxnet support spell checking

Tags: tensorflow, ocr, spell-checking, syntaxnet, spelling

I collect lots of words for a specific domain, I can train custom model based on the words.

In my usage there are lots of hard copy tables/sheets related to the domain, I will OCR those tables/sheets to structure documents. Anyway the OCR is not perfect, it always incorrectly recognizes some words. Can I use syntaxnet to do spell checking for optimizing the OCRed result?